# C: Trouble when trying to comvert HBITMAP into .bmp file

Tags: c, winapi, bitmap, bmp, hbitmap

I am creating a function to save a screenshot into a `.bmp` file, I've managed to save the screen into an `HBITMAP` but I'm having trouble when saving it. I would appreciate some help.

Here is the header with the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <wingdi.h>
#include <winuser.h>

typedef unsigned char u8;
typedef unsigned short u16;
typedef unsigned long u32;
typedef unsigned long long u64;

void getScreen()
{
    u16 screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);
    u16 screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);

    HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL); //get a desktop dc (NULL for entire screen)
    HDC hDest = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc); //create a dc for capture

    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);

    HBITMAP hbCapture = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    SelectObject(hDest, hbCapture);

    //Copy screen to bitmap
    BitBlt(hDest, 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

//test
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);

    char memBuffer[10000];
    BITMAPINFO bitmapInfo;
    bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = screenHeight;
    bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = screenWidth;
    bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = screenWidth * screenHeight * 3;
    bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;//NOT SURE
    bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 8; //NOT SURE
    bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
    GetDIBits(hDest, hbCapture, 0, screenHeight, &memBuffer, &bitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    FILE * fPointer = fopen("screen.png", "wb");//TO CHANGE
    WriteFile(fPointer, &memBuffer, (WORD) sizeof(memBuffer), 0, NULL);

    fclose(fPointer);
//test

    //Clean up
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
    DeleteDC(hDest);
    DeleteObject(hbCapture);
}
```

And here is also the main.c:

```
#include "main.h"

int main()
{
    getScreen();

    return 0;
}
```

I've already read all the questions about this topic in StackOverflow and none of them has clarified the issue for me.

Comment: You are mixing file I/O APIs. You can't use `WriteFile()` with `fopen()`.  You need to either 1) change `WriteFile()` to `fwrite()`, or 2) change `fopen()` to `CreateFile()` (and `fclose()` to `CloseHandle()`).  Also, see [Bitmap Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/bitmap-storage) on MSDN, which explains the *proper* format of a `.bmp` file.

Comment: also bmp file must begin with `BITMAPFILEHEADER`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = screenWidth * screenHeight * 3;
> ```

`biSize` is not the total pixel count, it's the size of bitmap info structure, it's always `sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)`.

You want to set `bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage` instead. This value is roughly (`width * height * bits_per_pixel/8`) but it has to be adjusted because each row is padded. Also don't mix `fopen` handle with `CreateFile` handle as noted in comments.

> ```
> fopen("screen.png", "wb");
> ```

You cannot save to png format using this method. You need a different library like Gdiplus for png format.

To save as bitmap, you have to setup `BITMAFILEHEADER`, `BITMAPINFOHEADER` and write them to file, and then write the bits obtained from `GetDIBits`

You may want to avoid using `typedef unsigned char u8;` etc. You can include `<stdint.h>` and use standard types `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`  etc. Or you can use standard Windows types like `BYTE`

```
void getScreen()
{
    int screenWidth  = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);
    int screenHeight  = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);

    HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
    HDC hDest = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP hbCapture = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, screenWidth , screenHeight );
    HBITMAP oldbmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hDest, hbCapture);
    BitBlt(hDest, 0, 0, screenWidth , screenHeight , hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    WORD bpp = 24; //<- bits per pixel
    int size = ((screenWidth  * bpp + 31) / 32) * 4 * screenHeight ;

    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmp_info_hdr;
    bmp_info_hdr.biSize = sizeof(bmp_info_hdr);
    bmp_info_hdr.biHeight  = screenHeight ;
    bmp_info_hdr.biWidth  = screenWidth ;
    bmp_info_hdr.biPlanes = 1;
    bmp_info_hdr.biBitCount = bpp;
    bmp_info_hdr.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bmp_info_hdr.biSizeImage = size;

    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmp_file_hdr;
    bmp_file_hdr.bfType = (WORD)'MB';
    bmp_file_hdr.bfOffBits = sizeof(bmp_file_hdr) + sizeof(bmp_info_hdr);
    bmp_file_hdr.bfSize = bmp_file_hdr.bfOffBits + size;

    char *buffer = malloc(size);
    GetDIBits(hDest, hbCapture, 0, screenHeight , buffer, 
        (BITMAPINFO*)&bmp_info_hdr, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    FILE * fPointer = fopen("screen.bmp", "wb");
    fwrite((char*)&bmp_file_hdr, sizeof(bmp_file_hdr), 1, fPointer);
    fwrite((char*)&bmp_info_hdr, sizeof(bmp_info_hdr), 1, fPointer);
    fwrite(buffer, size, 1, fPointer);
    fclose(fPointer);

    free(buffer);

    SelectObject(hDest, oldbmp);
    DeleteObject(hbCapture);
    DeleteDC(hDest);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
}
```